# Throwing back a URL in Django

Tags: python, django

This is a relatively straightforward question.

Is if possible for a method in `views.py` to dynamically throw back a URL that it caught in err and let a later handler process it. For example:

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('myapp.views',
    url(r'^foo/(?P<fiz>\d+)/?$', too_broad_method,name="foo"),
    url(r'^foo/bar/?$', just_right_method,name="foo"),
)
```

views.py

```
def too_broad_method(request,fiz=None):
    if fiz == some_dynamic_value:
        # under some runtime conditions fiz can equal bar
        # Throw some exception to give the URL back??
    else:
        return process_it()
```

Lets say for example, `/foo/bar` should be caught and processed by `too_broad_method` if an item has the name `bar` but otherwise it should be processed by `just_right_method`.

---

For extra context, I am trying to catch urls of the form `app_label/model_name`, which doesn't follow any pattern. I'd like these to be caught first, before anything else, which means using a very broad regex.

Comment: Why not use a redirect?

Comment: Or, better, why not put the foo/bar URL first so that it is matched first? That way you don't need any special logic.

Comment: Its an option, but there is a chance a redirect from `too_broad_method` to `/foo/bar/` may end in a redirect loop. I want to know if there is a way for a view to indicate to the url dispatcher it caught a url by mistake.

Comment: The dispatcher won't handle exceptions at all, so if you're trying to tell the dispatcher it's doing things wrong, that probably means you need to tweak your configuration. As I suggested above, maybe you should put `foo/bar` first to avoid this problem?

Comment: I've added some extra context. I know the URL dispatcher doesn't handle exceptions, hence the question. I could tweak the URLs, but I'd rather not.

Comment: Forgive me if this sounds snarky, but I don't see how you can expect the URL dispatcher to start working magically without tweaking the URL configuration. It's one thing if you don't control the URL configuration (i.e., if it comes from a third-party app), but if you control them, you should configure them properly. Please see my *modified* answer explaining how I think you could get it done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Edited since the entire premise of the question changed)

If you need to catch `app_name/model_name` URLs, my suggestion is that you generate your URL patterns dynamically. There's no reason you couldn't iterate through INSTALLED_APPS, get all available classes that inherit from `models.Model`, and create URL patterns in a list accordingly. Then you can feed that into the `patterns` function at the end.

Trying to inform the URL dispatcher that it was somehow "wrong" is misguided, as I've already explained, and you're [solving the wrong problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Instead, you should focus on configuring the URL patterns how you actually need them.

Comment: The issue is that this means foo/bar will never get used by too_broad_method.

Comment: I'm going to accept this, because after some soul searching I have to reluctantly admit that my URL pattern was terrible and should re-engineer it. Thanks for the harsh truth :P

Comment: Sorry if it was too harsh. If you have further difficulty with the above technique or anything else, you're always welcome to post another question. :-)

Comment: No, not too harsh at all, I've written much worse. I knew the URLs were crud, and the models names are not useful and have replaced them with nice stubs.